# What will happen when insert the `Thread.yield()` into an synchronized function

Tags: java, multithreading, task, synchronized

I'm learning about multiple threading in Java. Following is demo code, and I'm curious about the usage of `Thread.yield()` inside of the function.

Isn't it a *synchronized* function, which cannot be called until the running task finishes its work on it? Then what is the difference between inserting `Thread.yield()` into this block and not?

Demo code:

```
public class SynchronizeEvenGenerator {
private int currentEvenValue = 0;
/**
 * Generate even and return it
 * @return
 */
public synchronized int next() {
    ++currentEvenValue;
    Thread.yield();
    ++currentEvenValue;
    return currentEvenValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What will happen if `Thread.yield()` is called in a synchronized function?

As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield--) for `Thread.yield()` states:

> "[This is a] hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield its current use of a processor. The scheduler is free to ignore this hint."

So there are two possibilities:

1. Nothing happens; i.e. the `yield()` call returns immediately.
2. Another thread is scheduled and gets to execute.  Eventually, this thread is rescheduled and the `yield()` call returns.

One thing *does not happen*.  The thread *does not* relinquish the mutex.  Any other thread that happened to be blocked waiting to acquire the mutex will *remain* blocked.

---

> Isn't it a synchronized method, which cannot be called until the running task finishes its work on it?

`Thread.yield` is not a synchronized method.  (And even if it was, it would be locking the `Thread` object, not the lock that the `synchronized` block is currently holding.)

---

So, in your example, a call to `next()` is guaranteed to increment the counter by exactly 2.  If some other thread calls the `next()` method, the second call will remain blocked until (at least) after the first call returns.

The javadoc also says this:

> "It is rarely appropriate to use this method."

---

> Another question: Will it become an deadlock for thread scheduling

No.  The thread that called `yield()` will eventually be rescheduled.

(Deadlock is a very specific phenomenon (see [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)) that can only occur when a lock is acquired.  When a thread yields, it neither acquires or releases locks, so it cannot cause a deadlock.)

Now, when a thread yields, it might be a long time before it gets scheduled again, especially if there are lots of other runnable threads at the same *or higher* priority.  The net result is that other threads waiting to acquire the lock could held up for a long time.  This can unduly increase contention and congestion.  But eventually, the `yield()` call will return, the `next()` call will return and another thread will be able to acquire the lock.

In short: calling `yield()` while holding a lock is bad for performance, but it won't directly cause a deadlock.

As the javadoc says, calling `yield()` is rarely appropriate.

Comment: Another question: Will it become an deadlock for thread scheduling？

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't it an synchronized function which cannot be called until the running task finish it's work on it ?

It can't be running in another thread for the same object.

> Then what is the diff between insert Thread.yield() into this block and not ?

The CPU which is running the thread could be context switched to another available thread for any process on the system.

If there is no waiting thread to run, it will make it slower by about 15 - 30 micro-seconds.

c.f. wait(0) which can allow another thread to obtain the lock.

Comment: Just delay the method execute and will not make any other impact ?

Comment: @BinXiao correct, the thread could yield at that point any way, but it makes it much more likely.

Comment: So what is the available thread ? (Those thread not need to run this function ?)

Comment: @BinXiao Any thread in the same process, or any other process or one in the kernel. There will be thousands of possible threads which could run on your machine.